# Proving by contrapositive: xy is odd, if and only if x is odd and y is odd. x and y are integers

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I need to prove the following by contrapositive:

"xy is odd, if and only if x is odd and y is odd" x and y are integers

I know how the proof is done if it's "xy is odd, then x is odd and y is odd" but haven't grasped when it comes to "if and only if".

$$
( \text{ is odd}) \iff ( \text{ is even or } y \text{ is even})
$$

Based on my knowledge I assume I am able to use contraposition. But where do I start to use this?

Comment: "If and only if" means you prove both directions. So you have two implications, each of which you can use contraposition to prove.

Comment: Will it be possible for you to show the two implications? how they are written?

Comment: Why not just multiply them? If one of the numbers is even, say $x$, then $x=2n$ for some $n$. Then $xy=(2n)y=2(ny)$ which is even.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a statement "P if and only if Q" this means you have two statements to prove. You need to prove "If P, then Q" and "If Q, then P." This is what it means to prove both directions. So, if you wish to prove this by contraposition, you'll need to prove the statements "If not Q, then not P" and "If not P, then not Q."

Thus, to show $xy$ is odd iff (our shorthand for if and only if) $x$ and $y$ are odd by contraposition, you'll need to show:

1. $xy$ is even implies that $x$ or $y$ is even.
2. $x$ or $y$ even implies $xy$ is even.

Prove both of these and you're done.

Comment: Thanks, this helped alot :)

Comment: If it did, click the checkmark to accept this answer.